# Nested conditions for select in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to find nodes in my XML fulfilling a rather complex condition:
Find all the `record`s having a child `datafield` with an attribute `tag` having the value "020"

Here is an excerpt from the xml:

```
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" type="Bibliographic">
    <leader>01201nam a2200349 c 4500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="008">100218s2009    be ||||| |||| 00||||dut  </controlfield>
    <datafield tag="015" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">13,A50</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">dnb</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="016" ind1="7" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="2">DE-101</subfield>
      <subfield code="a">1000318389</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="020" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">9789044722369</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">kart.</subfield>
      <subfield code="9">978-90-447-2236-9</subfield>
    </datafield>
    ....
</record>
```

Currently I despair on formulating the XPath to match these records. I tried

```
<xsl:template match="//x:record[/x:datafield[@x:tag='020']]">
    ...
</xsl>
```

but no record is matched (x being the nmespace of the elements). But up to

```
<xsl:template match="//x:record[/x:datafield]">
    ...
</xsl>
```

it works (selects all `record`s having any `datafield` children).
What do I do wrong? Is it not allowed to nest conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default namespaces only apply to element nodes, not to attribute nodes so for the attribute you need to use `@tag` and not `@x:tag`.

And `//` at the beginning of a match pattern is not necessary. Furthermore, the `x:datafield` elements are children so use a relative path `match="x:record[x:datafield[@tag = '020']]"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get these records somewhere in between the clutter of texts of all the records which don't match, so I first didn't recognize them. How can I best remove these texts? Define a complementary template?

Comment: You basically have two options, the first is to make sure you select only those records when processing starts with e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="//x:record[x:datafield[@tag = '020']]"/></xsl:template>`, the second is to suppress output of other nodes with e.g. `<xsl:template match="x:record[not(x:datafield[@tag = '020'])]"/>`.